# Postgresql tsvector structure

Tags: postgresql, tsvector

lo here.

i am trying to utilizing tsvector for counting frequencies of terms.
i think i am almost there but i cannot find a way to obtain terms from tsvector structure.

what I have done is, after creating tsvector column:

`select term_tsv, count(*) count from (select unnest(term_tsv) term_tsv from document_tsv) t group by term_tsv order by count desc;`

the result is like: 

        `stem_tsv        | count
------------------------+-------
 (3,{9},{D})            |     1`

i am lost for not knowing what kind of expression the parenthesis represents.
can anybody tell me how to extract the term from shell?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i figured out that something like the following lists top 10 frequent entries,
which was written in the official manual.

`SELECT * FROM ts_stat('SELECT vector FROM apod')
ORDER BY nentry DESC, ndoc DESC, word
LIMIT 10;`

just for record.